# How does AWS Autoscaling work? (the missing part)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

when you put your instances on autoscale & set the minimum & maximum limit , does it scale to the maximum anyway or does it check for the threshold for each instance created by as and then spawn?

As in , 1 instance triggers an alarm for 90% cpu usage -> AutoScale creates 1 instance more (total 2) -> *`does it check for 90% cpu usage on both the instances & THEN create new instances or does it create new instances anyway after the cooldown time`* ?

Answer (score 2):

Auto scaling will observe the average CPU usage of every instance and then decide if a new instance is needed or an existing can be shut down. This will ensure that you only use (and pay for) what you need.

Comment: Does it mean that if one of the instances has reached the 90% cpu utilization, auto-scaling will add instances even if other instances in that group are using less CPU for e.g. 10% ? This may happen if there is a cron or something on that instance.

Comment: It's also taking the overall system load into account, so no worries about that. If you have an instance dedicated to some background tasks handled via a cron you may should consider to take it out of your load balancing array.